# How to filter results in graphql?

Tags: graphql

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
 query Publications($id: ProfileId!) {
    publications(
      request: { profileId: $id }
    ) {
      items {
        typename
      }
    }
  }
```

And I get a result like so:

```
{
  "data": {
    "publications": {
      "items": [
        {
          "typename": "Article"
        },
        {
          "typename": "Post"
        },
        {
          "typename": "Post"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do I filter my results so I *only* get the `"typename": "Article"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add a second optional parameter to your query:

```
query Publications($id: ProfileId!, $typename: String) {
    publications(
      request: { profileId: $id , typename: $typename}
    ) {
      items {
        typename
      }
    }
  }
```

Then in your resolver, if you see that `typename` has a value, filter your results to match.

Comment: Right, but if that's not an option, how would i filter the results?

Comment: Then you'd have to filter on the client. Unless your schema has filter operations built-in (query variables that can specify where clauses, sorts, etc…) Maybe look at the `publications` query definition to see what it supports?

Comment: ah, so graphql itself can't filter, you have to filter it client side once you get the API response?

Comment: Exactly. It's a query language without a `where` clause.